# Is there an error in the algebra of this GMAT problem explanation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

A problem I found on [this site](https://www.test-guide.com/gmat/free-gmat-practice-tests/gmat-data-sufficiency-practice-test-3.html) is stated as follows:

> Determine the value of $t$.
>
> 1. $2t + 6s = 8$
> 2. $t/2 - 2 = - 3s/4$

One is supposed to determine whether or not the problem can be solved by the given conditions (1 and 2).

Here is the official explanation of the answer:

Correct answer is: Statements (1) and (2) TOGETHER are NOT sufficient to answer the question asked, and additional data specific to the problem are needed.

> Correct answer: Statements (1) and (2) TOGETHER are NOT sufficient. In
>   statement 1, $2t + 6s = 8$ is one equation is two unknowns, hence we
>   cannot determine the value of t. The statement is insufficient. In
>   statement 2, $t/2 - 2 = -3s/4$ can be transformed to $t - 4 = -6s/2$. But
>   this is an equation with two unknowns hence we cannot determine the
>   value of $t$. The statement is insufficient. Combining the two
>   statements, we have  2, $t/2 - 2 = -3s/4$ which can be transformed to $t
>  - 4 = -6s/2$ then to $2t - 8 = -6s$ but this is equal to the equation $2t + 6s = 8$, hence we have an equation with two unknowns. Thus, we cannot determine the value of $t$; the statements (1) and (2) TOGETHER are NOT
>   sufficient.

My problem is with this statement:

> In statement 2, $t/2 - 2 = -3s/4$ can be transformed to $t - 4 = -6s/2$.

If both sides are multiplied by $4$, shouldn't it be $2t - 8 = -3s$?

In the end, my answer was

> BOTH statements (1) and (2) TOGETHER are sufficient to answer the
>   question asked, but NEITHER statement ALONE is sufficient to answer
>   the question ask

Which is correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: I agree with @Paul. Also, the reasons given for insufficiency of each statement taken alone are not correct: "*this is an equation with two unknowns hence we cannot determine the value of* $t$" Note that $s^2 + t^2 = 0$ is one equation in two unknowns for which $(s,t) = (0,0)$ is the only (real) solution. In fact, depending on how "linear equation in two variables" is defined, $2(t - 2s) + 4s = 10$ could be considered as **one linear equation in two variables** for which we can determine the value of $t$ (although not the value of $s,$ but the question only asks for the value of $t).$

Answer (score 1):

You are obviously correct : the equations, treated together, admit the solution $t =4 , s= 0$.

The mistake is in the part indicated : indeed, the "can be transformed" part is incorrect. However, note that if $2.$ were changed to $2. \frac t2 - 2 = -\frac{3s}2$ then in fact said transformation can be completed. It seems to be an error of computation or in the original question, in that case.

I just went through the entire test on your site, and yes, it is a bad error which needs correction.

EDIT : For completeness, I will add Dave Renfro's comment. Given one equation in two unknowns, it is in fact possible that both unknowns can be found from that equation alone. For example, $s^2+t^2 = 0$ is uniquely possible only with $s=t=0$ (over reals, or rationals/integers if you like). Even under the restriction of this being linear, $3(t-2s)+6s = 6$ is satisfied by a unique $t$ and any $s$, so one variable is still getting fixed.

The necessary and sufficient condition for two equations of the form $ax+by + c = 0$ and $dx+ey+f = 0$ to be simultaneously satisfied by a unique pair of $x,y$ is that $ae \neq bd$. In your case, you have $2t+6s - 8 = 0$ and $t/2 + 3s/4 - 2 = 0$. We have $a=2,b=6,d=\frac 12, e = \frac 34$ ,so $ae = 1.5$ and $bd = 3$. These are not equal, giving a unique satisfying pair.

Suppose $ae = bd$ , then $\frac{a}{d} = \frac{b}{e}$ (assuming $d,e \neq 0$ , else the second equation will be degenerate). If $c=f=0$ or if $f \neq 0$ and $\frac{c}{f}$ equals those fractions above, then the two equations have infinitely many simultaneous solutions. Else, they don't have any simultaneous solution.